# How to read variables from stdin dynamically and store them into an array

Tags: bash, array, read

The problem is to read variables with read command dynamically from a read command in bash without knowing how many they are in advance and store them into an array .

I  tested with :

```
read -p "array : " array[{0..#}]
```

as

```
read -p "array : " array[{0..3}]
```

works

But with no success .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the read usage output you can actually use the `-a` flag.

```
read -p "array: " -a array
```

Comment: you're right , how i miss that !!! ^^

Comment: @Begoul I just updated my answer check again.